# Rendering a string in Java which is in different languages english, chinese and Indic

Tags: java, swing

I need to render the below `String` on a `JTable` cell. How do we do this?

> testä漢字1ગુજરાતી2

**Update:**

Looks like my question is not clear. The above string is a name of file. Need to display this and many other file names in JTable. Data comes dynamically. I may need a custom renderer to display this string exactly same. Currently, this displays junk characters. Simply changing the table Font from Calibri to MS Gothic, I can see the chinese characters, but not indic letters. But, as the data comes dynamically, we won't be knowing what font to use.

So, want to know if there is way so that I can check the string programmatically and render the string with different fonts as appropriate.

Comment: Have you tried something? May be using `Locale`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a font which is more complete. I believe the DejaVu family is decent, others may be able to suggest better. The [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html) suggests that the logical fonts `Dialog`, `DialogInput`, `Monospaced`, `Serif` and `SansSerif` are also likely to be more complete. Potentially they could map to multiple underlying fonts depending on the specific characters which need to be rendered. Oracle also mentions the Lucidia family which is distributed with Oracle's JRE as another possibility which is fairly complete, though it doesn't have Chinese, Korean or Japanese characters.

A more convoluted solution would be to run `Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c)` on the characters in each string, assemble a `Set<Character.UnicodeBlock>` and guess which font is most appropriate based on the blocks present in the string, or even write a custom renderer to render each character (or sequence of characters) with a font appropriate to the Unicode block they belong to. Unicode blocks tend to be categorized according to the script they contain.